# Did google start using proxy for gmail images?

Tags: proxy, ip, gmail

Normally, whenever someone sends an e-mail to someone else, some measures can be taken in order to track the reciver's IP; if the receiver and only the receiver gets the image, you can easily tell his IP.
I did notice something with google:
whenever I get an image in GMAIL, and I check the URL, I see this:

```
https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/longstring#realImageURL
```

I think this is something new with google, which disables this kind of attack. notice the /proxy/ in the address above. what do you think? can someone confirm? are they using proxy in order to prevent this kind of attack?

Answer (score 3):

From what I know is that Google deployed image proxy servers in 2013.

Here is an old news about that https://wordtothewise.com/2013/12/gmail-deploys-image-proxy-servers/

> Sometime very recently (last 24-48 hours), we are seeing that Google made a change to Gmail such that all image URLs in the email
>   content are replaced by a call to Google’s content caching service
>   googleusercontent.com.
>
> For example, an image with the src: “http://mysite.com/i.jpg” will be replaced by Gmail with a URL something like this:
>   https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/…#http://mysite.com/i.jpg